# Steps to run localDB on new server

Tags: sql-server

I have an old application, which i am moving to new server. I haven't worked on this application.

It is using localDB placed in app_data folder.

```
<add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data source=database;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

I have installed SQL Server 2014 enterprise edition.

What steps are required to run this database. I am getting error of invalid key.
Is it required to install express version?

Comment: restore your old database and use that

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you want to use the [`User Instance`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254504%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) feature, you need to have SQL Server Express Edition.

This is one of the few times where a higher-level edition doesn't support a feature supported by a lower edition.